# FutureBuilder<List> is not displaying any data

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, dart, flutter

I am writing a flutter app that is listing the whole players of a card game. And if no players are inside the database, then there should be a text that is saying, that is no data found. But my problem is inside the `getStatistik()`. That function is returning no data.

This is my code where I want to display the player in sort of a ranking:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:watten/model/statistik.dart';
import 'package:watten/database/database.dart';
import 'package:watten/statistik/deleteStatistikDialog.dart';

Future<List<Statistik>> fetchStatistik() async{
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  List<Statistik> statistik = await dbHelper.getStatistik();
  print("Length: "+statistik.length.toString()");
  return statistik;
}


class Spielerstatistik extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Spielerstatistik();
}

class _Spielerstatistik extends State<Spielerstatistik>{

  List statistik;
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  bool datenVorhanden = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF9C27B0),
        title: new Text("Ranking")
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder<List<Statistik>>(
        future: fetchStatistik(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                          return new Card(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: new Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ListTile(
                                    leading: platzNr
                                        ? platzierung
                                        : new Text("     ${index+1}"),
                                    title: new Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        new Container(
                                          child: new Text(
                                            snapshot.data[index].name,
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          width: 80.0,
                                        ),
                                        new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0)),
                                        new Container(
                                          child: new Text(
                                            snapshot.data[index].spielanzahl.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          width: 55.0,
                                        ),
                                        new Container(
                                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              border: new Border(
                                                  left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26)
                                              )
                                          ),
                                          height: 40.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 22.0),
                                        ),
                                        new Container(
                                          child: new Text(
                                            snapshot.data[index].gewonneneSpiele.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(color: textfarbe),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          width: 12.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                                        ),
                                        new Container(
                                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              border: new Border(
                                                  left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26)
                                              )
                                          ),
                                          height: 40.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                        ),
                                        new Container(
                                          child: new Text(
                                            snapshot.data[index].erfolgsquote.roundToDouble().toString() + " %",//Erfolgsquote
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          width: 65.0,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                    )
                )
              ],
            );
          } else if(snapshot.data.length == 0){

            return new Text("No Data found!");

          }
          return new Container(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my code where I get the data for the database from:

```
Future<List<Statistik>> getStatistik() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM statistik');
    List<Statistik> statistik = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
      statistik.add(new Statistik(name: list[i]["$statistikName"] , spielanzahl: list[i]["$statistikSpielanzahl"], gewonneneSpiele: list[i]["$statistikWins"], erfolgsquote: list[i]["erfolgsquote"]));
    }
    return statistik;
  }
```

My thoughts are that the FutureBuilder is not even making a real call, because `print("Length: "+statistik.length.toString()");` that I built in, wasn't printing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `snapshot.hasData` is false, `snapshot.data` equals `null`. Therefore you can't do

`if (snapshot.hasData) {} else if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {}`

Instead just do a `if (snapshot.hasData == false)`

Comment: That solved the problem with the error. But there is still no data coming from the database. And I'm pretty sure about it that there is some data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no need to use `$`. Try the below code snippet. It is explained [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-sqlite-database-example.html) in detail.

```
Future<List<Statistik>> getStatistik() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM statistik');
    List<Statistik> statistik = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
      statistik.add(new Statistik(name: list[i]["statistikName"] , spielanzahl: list[i]["statistikSpielanzahl"], gewonneneSpiele: list[i]["statistikWins"], erfolgsquote: list[i]["erfolgsquote"]));
    }
    return statistik;
  }
```